# Install Ubuntu replacing Windows 10 in Lenovo Thinkpad x13 2021

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I have a laptop Lenovo Thinkpad x13 gen2 from 2021

I have 3 partitions, 1 with Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu deleting only this partition and keeping the other two.

In order to do so I make a USB flash boot device with Rufus and `ubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`

I enter BIOS setup and make save boot off and when I select the boot device, booting from my USB drive this is what happens:

[image]

A Grub console shows up, and then when I write boot guess what:

```
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Where is the way to proceed? I really need to install Ubuntu

PS: I want to mention the fact that this laptop has Bitlocker installed, and that all partitions have NTFS type

Comment: Try running the installation again. Make sure that your BIOS settings are correct and that Fastboot and Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: If system is that new, you should wait until April 21 and try 22.04. But this site does not support 22.04 until released. Velry new hardware typically needs newest distribution to have latest kernel & drivers that are needed for that new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that this was an inherited grub from a dual boot windwos 10/linux mint.
All I had to do was select my boot options and select usb booteable device and all was ok to continue from there,
Now I have ubuntu installed

BUT to grub menus pops up!! :(

I will make a new question here : [I 've installed Ubuntu and now have two grub popping up!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402740/i-ve-installed-ubuntu-and-now-have-two-grub-popping-up)