# I 've installed Ubuntu and now have two grub popping up!

Tags: boot, grub2

First I make a dual boot laptop with windows 10 and linux mint
then I delete everything and only installed Ubuntu
BUT
when it starts this is what happens:
1.lenovo logo
2.grub menu (I don't touch it)
3.lenovo logo
4.grub menu (I don't touch it)
5.lenovo and ubuntu logo

all this happens very fast, but it doesn t feel rigth
I just want to start directly for ubuntu, as is the only OS installed

I've found a way to hide grub menu modifying /etc/default/grub:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm5kurfejzw (replaced "/bin/sh" to "/bin/bash" as @Denys Sedchenko  and for fixing the hwmatch  just fallow https://unixcop.com/fix-the-error-cant-find-the-command-hwmatch-on-grub/)...but still something is missing

I will share this:

```
root@tita-2:/home/jotas# dpkg --list | grep grub
ii  grub-common                                   2.04-1ubuntu26.13                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-customizer                               5.1.0-2                                    amd64        GUI to configure GRUB2 and BURG
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                            2.04-1ubuntu44.2                           amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 modules)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                         1.167.2+2.04-1ubuntu44.2                   amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  grub-gfxpayload-lists                         0.7                                        amd64        GRUB gfxpayload blacklist
ii  grub-pc                                       2.04-1ubuntu26.13                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
ii  grub-pc-bin                                   2.04-1ubuntu26.13                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS modules)
ii  grub2-common                                  2.04-1ubuntu26.13                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
```

thanks in advance for your time

EDIT: After the steps mentioned here: [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after custom installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu/1042032#1042032)

I was able to delete de windows boot manager but my system doesn t boot directly into ubuntu...this is what I have now:

`sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI`

`Boot  ubuntu`

and with:
`sudo efibootmgr`

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0010,0011,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016,001A,001B,001C,001D,001E,001F,0020,0021,0022
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0010  Setup
Boot0011  Boot Menu
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0014  Asset Information
Boot0015  Regulatory Information
Boot0016  ThinkShield secure wipe
Boot0017  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0018  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0019  MEBx Hot Key
Boot001A* USB CD
Boot001B* USB FDD
Boot001C* NVMe0
Boot001D* USB HDD
Boot001E* PXE BOOT
Boot001F* LENOVO CLOUD
Boot0020* ON-PREMISE
Boot0021  Other CD
Boot0022  Other HDD
Boot0023* IDER BOOT CDROM
Boot0024* IDER BOOT Floppy
Boot0025* ATA HDD
Boot0026* ATAPI CD
```

Maybe we need to delete Boot Menu for jumping right away into ubuntu only?

Comment: How did you "delete everything" before installing Ubuntu?  Did you format the entire hard drive?

Comment: i 've just installed ubuntu in the windows partition

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu/1042032#1042032 it is not the same problem, but it may help.

Comment: I will edit the question, based on fallowing these steps and having new considerations

Comment: You didn't delete anything then. I suggest that you format the hard drive. This will actually remove all traces of operating systems from the computer.  Then reinstall Ubuntu. You can use the "Disks" application from the liveUSB (Try Ubuntu from USB installation media).

Comment: reinstall is not an option :)